# Error when i try to convert file using imagemagick

Tags: node.js, express

I try to make a PDF file cover in JPG for this I use Node JS and the following libraries ImageMagick Graphicsmagick and Ghostcript.

Code:

root/controller/convertorController.js

```
const path = require('path');
const {exec} = require('child_process')

let baseDir = path.join(__dirname,'../tmp');

exports.customExecution = async(req,res,next)=>{


console.log(testDir)
exec(`magick convert ${testDir} -quality 100 awbtest.jpg`,(err,stdout,stderr)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        console.log('success')
        next();
    }
})

}
```

Project Structure

[image]

I checked the file path is correct if when I execute the function does nothing:

```
Error: Command failed: magick convert D:\Project\pdf-jpg convertor\tmp/test.pdf -quality 100 awbtest.jpg
 convert: unable to open image 'D:\Project\pdf-jpg convertor\tmp/test.pdf': No such file 
or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3570.
 convert: no images defined `awbtest.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3342.

at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5) {
killed: false,
code: 1,
signal: null,
cmd: 'magick convert D:\Project\pdf-jpg convertor\tmp/test.pdf -quality 100 
 awbtest.jpg'
 }
```

Comment: You are trying to access an input file called `D:\Project\pdf-jpg convertor\tmp/test.pdf` That is two files, not one.  When reading a PDF, put the density before the file.  Also for Imagemagick 7, use magick, not magick convert.

Comment: It is two files since you have a space after pdf-jpg and before converter.  If that is really just a directory with a space in it, then you must put your whole input path including the file in quotes